# How to access the params variable in helper specs

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec2

I am writing some specs for helpers that check for values in the params variable. Until now I have been doing:

```
helper.stub!(:params).and_return(:user => {:username => "jack"})
```

The problem is that while the actual params Hash has string/symbol-agnostic keys and `params[:user] == params["user"]`, my implementation does not and produces various failures where it should not.

**Is there a way to set the proper (key-type agnostic) params variable in helper specs?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

THe easiest way to do this is to use `with_indifferent_access`.

In your case :

```
helper.stub!(:params).and_return({:user => {:username => "jack"}}.with_indifferent_access)
```